# How to take certain values from an array and add them, then add that value to a second array?

Tags: java, arrays, input

NOT ALLOWED TO USE ARRAYLIST

Hey Guys! Thanks for taking the time to read!

I have an array currently with 15 numbers in it, I need to add the numbers from the spots 1-5, then from 2-6, then from 3,7 etc all the way till 15. And then the sum of these have to be put into a new array.

Any tips?

The code is below

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Asgn7
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {   
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("asgn7data.txt"));

        int[] array = new int[file.nextInt()];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = file.nextInt();
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

        file.close();

    }

}
```

This is the input file.

```
1
1
4
6
4
7
11
8
10
6
10
13
6
10
15
```

Comment: What do you want exactly please?

Comment: Please modify you question to include the input file. We need to see how the information is structured there? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: @Raf , Input file added.

Comment: @YassinHajaj  I Have an array of numbers which i read from a file. I now need to add the values from the days 1-5, 2-6, 3-7 etc. And then divide these by five then store them into another array.

Comment: @JonRoy Thank you for the effort but copy-pasting the same exact sentence from the question does not help me understand the question. Would you mind rephrasing it? Why are you speaking about days for example?

Comment: @YassinHajaj Sure, my bad. I have an array currently. With 15 numbers in it, I need to add the numbers from 1-5, then from 2-6, then from 3,7 etc all the way till 15. And then the sum of these have to be put into a new array.              EDIT: The days should not have been there, should have been numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you need is a second array empty and just a correct algorithm to make this work. Here we just loop over the five next ints and add them to the same index from the second array.

---

### Solution

```
String ints = "15 1 1 4 6 4 7 11 8 10 6 10 13 6 10 15";
Scanner file = new Scanner(ints);
int[] array = new int[file.nextInt()];
int[] newArray = new int[array.length-4];
int counter = 0;
while (file.hasNextInt()) array[counter++] = file.nextInt();
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length - 4 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++){
        newArray[i] += array[i+j];
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

---

### Output

```
[16, 22, 32, 36, 40, 42, 45, 47, 45, 45, 54]
```

Comment: Thank you dude! Makes sense now, I knew i needed two arrays but this makes quite a bit of sense. Thanks man

Comment: @JonRoy You're welcome Jon :)

Comment: Theres one thing i dont understand,  its the array[counter++] = file.nextInt();  Shouldn't that be inside of the while loop?

Comment: This is just the filling of the first array with the data from the file. Nothing special, it just fills index after index until the file has not int's anymore :)

Comment: Hm, When running the code, if i am trying to figure out how many variables are in the first Array, It is only printing 11/15, i presume it has something to do with the .length() -4, Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
int[] inputarray = new int[10]; // You take a fixed size because you don't necessarily know the actual amount of input, we will expand this like an arraylist would
// First we will collect the input data
int current_index = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    if (inputarray.length == current_index) {
        // Expand the array by creating a new one
        final int[] expanded = new int[inputarray.length * 2];
        System.arraycopy(inputarray, 0, expanded, 0, inputarray.length);
        inputarray = expanded;
    }
    inputarray[current_index++] = scanner.nextInt();
}

// now we can calculate
final int[] answers = new int[current_index + 1 - 5];
for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        answers[i] += inputarray[i + j];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(answers));
```